I need help understanding trailing slash behaviour in Nginx
I'm setting up nginx as a reverse proxy for squaremap (a world map viewer for Minecraft servers) and encountering unexpected behavior with trailing slashes. I've followed the squaremap documentation for serving with nginx acting as a reverse proxy (https://github.com/jpenilla/squaremap/wiki/Internal-vs-External-Web-Server), but I'm confused by the results. Here's what I've tried:
squaremap is running at 127.0.0.1:39000
Configuration:
1.
location /squaremap {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:39000;
}

Result: Accessing https://example.com/squaremap returns a 404 error.
2.
location /squaremap {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:39000/;
}

Result: https://example.com/squaremap shows a blank page, but https://example.com/squaremap/ works fine.
3.
location /squaremap/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:39000/;
}

Result: https://example.com/squaremap redirects to https://example.com/squaremap/ and then displays the web interface.
https://example.com/squaremap/ works as expected.
In my attempt to figure out what was happening, I read part of the nginx documentation on proxy_pass. However, I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct. My understanding is:

If there's no URI in the proxy_pass directive, the request URI is passed to the upstream unchanged.
If there is a URI in the proxy_pass directive, the part of the request matching the location directive is substituted by the value of the URI in the proxy_pass directive.

Based on this, I created a table of what I think is happening in each of the above cases:



Case
Original Request
Request to Upstream
Result




1
https://example.com/squaremap
/squaremap
Error 404


2.a
https://example.com/squaremap
/
White page


2.b
https://example.com/squaremap/
//
Works


3
https://example.com/squaremap/
/
Works



My questions are:

Is my interpretation of how nginx processes these requests correct?
Why do I get different results in cases 2a and 3, even though they seem to send the same request to the upstream?
Why doesn't it work without the trailing slash, but works with it?
Is there a configuration that would allow both /squaremap and /squaremap/ to work correctly without a redirect?

I'd appreciate any insights into understanding this behavior and how to properly configure nginx for this use case.

Your table looks accurate and case 3 looks like the correct configuration. You also have to think about the asset URLs (css,js,etc.), and only 3 will translate those correctly.

@RichardSmith Can you please explain why the setup in case 2b works? Let's consider the request for /squaremap/js/modules/Squaremap.js. Case 2 will translate this to //js/modules/Squaremap.js, so why am I still able to access Squaremap's interface at https://example.org/squaremap/, but https://example.org/squaremap doesn't work and gives me only a blank white page?

I used Developer Tools to figure out what was going on and observed many errors in the console for case 2a. Requests were being made to https://example.com/js/modules/Squaremap.js, and the server was replying with a status of 404. However, in case 2b, there was no error, and my browser was correctly loading assets from https://example.com/squaremap/js/modules/Squaremap.js.

Looking at your results case by case,

In case 1, you are sending the request upstream without changing it. So we can assume that the service on 127.0.0.1:39000 does not want to receive the /squaremap prefix in the URL.
All other cases remove the /squaremap prefix from the URL before passing the request to 127.0.0.1:39000.

In case 2, there are two potential problems.
The html page that is received by the browser contains the URLs of resource files (CSS, JS, images), and these may be specified in a number of ways. One of which is path-relative (e.g. src=js/modules/Squaremap.js). The browser will convert that into an absolute URL before passing it to the Nginx server. The browser will us the final / in the URL of the html page to form a base for path-relative URLs.
So https://example.com/squaremap will use a base of https://example.com/ so src=js/modules/Squaremap.js will be requested from https://example.com/js/modules/Squaremap.js which will not match the correct location block.
However https://example.com/squaremap/ will use a base of https://example.com/squaremap/ so src=js/modules/Squaremap.js will be requested from https://example.com/squaremap/js/modules/Squaremap.js which is correct.
The second problem is that even if the correct URL is requested, (e.g. https://example.com/squaremap/js/modules/Squaremap.js) it will be translated incorrectly to http://127.0.0.1:39000//js/modules/Squaremap.js.
Nginx silently folds // into a single /, but other services may react differently.
Either problem might cause the resources to fail to load correctly which may be the cause of the white page.

Case 3 looks fine.
